# microbit why blinking leds is so slow?

Tags: pause, bbc-microbit

Using this basic example code from microbit, **blinking heart**, I tried to change the delay of blinking with the pause argument. However, the minimum actual blinking frequency is around 500ms, no matter what value i put.

Do you know why, and how I can achieve much faster blinking with led patterns (like `show_icon` or `show_leds` function).

```
def on_forever():
    basic.show_icon(IconNames.HEART)
    basic.pause(50)
    basic.show_icon(IconNames.SMALL_HEART)
    basic.pause(50)
basic.forever(on_forever)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tagged this as `micropython` but I don't believe that is what you are using. I think you are running with the Python in the MakeCode editor.

Looking at the help page for for the MakeCode [show_icon](https://makecode.microbit.org/reference/basic/show-icon), it says it is called with:

```py
def basic.show_icon(icon: IconNames, interval: null): None
```

with the following details about `interval`:

> `interval` (optional), the time to display in milliseconds. default is
> 600.

As you were not putting a value for `interval` it was defaulting to `600` milliseconds which meant your code was putting `650` milliseconds delay between each icon.

I was able to vary the duration an icon was displayed with the following:

```py
def on_forever():
    basic.show_icon(IconNames.HEART, 100)
    basic.show_icon(IconNames.SMALL_HEART, 400)
    basic.show_icon(IconNames.HEART, 100)
    basic.show_icon(IconNames.SMALL_HEART, 800)

basic.forever(on_forever)
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right! Actually it seems that the interval option does not exist on the block coding interface. You have to choose python to use it. Anyway, i think other people might come into the same problem, thanks for the answer.